# Facebook Login, catch birthday friend using the same app FB SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, calendar

I would like to NSLog the birthday date of my friends who are using the same app.
I've found how to NSLog the name, but the birthday NSLog "null".
I'm using FB SDK 2.0

Here is my code : 
LoginViewController.m :

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender
{
    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"email", @"user_birthday", @"friends_birthday", @"friends_location", @"friends_hometown"];

    // Login PFUser using facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

        if (user) {
            [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                    NSLog(@"permissions::%@",FBSession.activeSession.permissions);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];

     }
```

CalendarViewController.m :

```
#import "CalendarViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface CalendarViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalendarViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location"];
    [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) {
            NSLog(@"%@:%@", [friend name],[friend birthday]);
        }}];
}
```

Here are my NSLog :

```
permissions::(
    installed,
    "public_profile",
    email,
    "user_birthday",
    "user_relationships",
    "user_location",
    "user_activities",
    "user_friends",
    "user_about_me"
)
2014-08-13 23:24:51.339 Mindle[4023:60b] Jean Dupont:(null)
```

Comment: You can only fetch a users own birthday.

Comment: in addition to wizkids comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog